# Convert a data frame with integer columns to a list column, where each element in the list is an integer vector

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr

I would like to convert a 7 column data frame, *icols*, into a list column of integer vectors.

```
 icols <- structure(list(CBT = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 1), MI = c(0, 1, 1, 1, 1), 
        Educ = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Fam = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0), CM = c(0, 
        0, 0, 0, 0), PeerGroup = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0), ICM = c(0, 0, 
        0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
    "data.frame"))
```

The code below creates a vector of character strings.

```
  > do.call(paste, as.data.frame(icols))
    [1] "0 0 0 0 0 0 0" "0 1 0 0 0 0 0" "0 1 0 0 0 0 0" "1 1 0 0 0 0 0" "1 1 0 0 0 0 0"
```

I would like to create a list column, in which the 7 elements of each string become an integer vector.

Desired output is something like:

```
     CBT    MI  Educ   Fam    CM PeerGroup   ICM  new_column
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl> <dbl>   <list>
 1     0     0     0     0     0         0     0   <int [7]>
 ...
```

Comment: Do you need `split(icols, 1:nrow(icols))`

Comment: If you want as a vector `split(unlist(icols, use.names = FALSE), row(icols))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option with `tidyverse` would be

```
library(tidyverse)
icols %>% 
    mutate(desired_column = pmap(., ~ c(..., use.names = FALSE)))
# A tibble: 5 x 8
#    CBT    MI  Educ   Fam    CM PeerGroup   ICM desired_column
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl> <dbl> <list>        
#1     0     0     0     0     0         0     0 <dbl [7]>     
#2     0     1     0     0     0         0     0 <dbl [7]>     
#3     0     1     0     0     0         0     0 <dbl [7]>     
#4     1     1     0     0     0         0     0 <dbl [7]>     
#5     1     1     0     0     0         0     0 <dbl [7]>
```

If the 'desired_column' should be `integer` class

```
icols %>% 
    mutate(desired_column = pmap(., ~ c(..., use.names = FALSE) %>% 
              as.integer))
```

---

Or with `split` from `base R`

```
icols$desired_column <- split(unlist(icols, use.names = FALSE), row(icols))
```

Comment: The mapping version in base R would similarly be `icols$desired_column <- do.call(Map, c(c,icols,use.names=FALSE))`